# Ctrl-F in 2022 matlab editor: finding past search keywords

Tags: matlab

In all versions of the Matlab editor pre-2021, I used to be able to find previous keywords I searched for (ctrl-F). This was intuitive to find in the search bar tool, and greatly helped to navigate the code and find function names I've searched before. In the current version (2021b, 64 bit windows) I no longer see this option (or at least it's not easy to find), so have to manually type function names each time. Has this been disabled or hidden? Where is the search history in MATLAB located in versions starting in R2022a?

Answer (score 2):

On macOS and Windows, pressing <kbd>down arrow</kbd> while the Find window is active opens the list of previous search terms. Then use the up/down arrow keys to scroll through the list, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select a term and perform a Find on that term.

Comment: Thank you, Adriaan! I should have tried to experiment more. I found that on my windows the down arrow works right away (no windows key) brings up the list.

Comment: You are correct, only the arrow key is required. I edited my answer. Its pretty intuitive once you know it, but I don't know where it is documented.